# Managing paths in Python projects

Tags: python

Is there a more efficient way of dealing with hardcoded paths in Python? I find myself in the below situation where I'm appending strings together to land in the desired directory, but I don't want to inadvertently break code if I were to move files around. Is there a way to maybe tokenize these directory paths in a config file and then manage them from that location? If so how?

```
scripts_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + "/../scripts"
```

Comment: You should use `os.path.join` to join paths, not `+`. Also, if the script location can change, you should pass it in as an argument, not hard code it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I list all files of a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory)

Comment: [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html), part of the standard library and should replace `os`.  [Python 3's pathlib Module: Taming the File System](https://realpython.com/python-pathlib/)

Comment: My question was more about how to refactor directory paths when using Python. In my previous team we used to just keep in in a config file and the build process would de-tokenize references to them in the code, but all these are great suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where to put data files is a common problem and different applications handle it in different ways. Some ideas:

- Standardize a directory to read all files relative to or the location of a
  config file that specifies this, then put all files to read in there. This is
  used by the Apache server, nginx, Vim, and many other programs. There's
  actually [a spec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1024339) that tells you where
  you should put it. It's not universally followed but I like it.

For example, to customize the Vim app, put config in `~/.vimrc`, and other
configs in `~/.vim` in Unix-like operating systems (Windows has corresponding
locations)

- Pass config through environmental variables or command line arguments to the
  app. This approach is used by most apps designed to be run via Docker.

Example:

`myapp --script-dir=../scripts` or `myapp --config conf.cfg` or `APP_NAME_DIR=/tmp myapp`

- bake the data into the deployable. For Python, you can use the [MANIFEST.in](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/non-code-files.html) file to have pip package it. This approach is used by apps where the data is read-only (which sounds like your case) and it makes it easier to deploy. The Flask [docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/distribute/#distributing-resources) have some notes on how do to this.

You can combine some of these approaches. Maybe you want your app to look for a base dir name first in an environmental variable (like `<app_name>_base_dir`), and if that doesn't exist, in `~/.config/<app_name>` or something. I recommend checking how some of your favorite apps solve this problem for more inspiration.

Once you have the base_dir path from somewhere, I highly recommend the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) library to manipulate paths. It comes with newer versions of Python and lets you do things like this:

```
from pathlib import Path

base_dir = Path(__file__).parent  # consider approaches above to get base_dir
script_dir = base_dir / 'scripts'
print(script_dir)
# prints: <location of this file>/scripts
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the exact information I was looking for